# Testing Django view requiring user authentication with Factory Boy

Tags: django, django-unittest, factory-boy

I need a view that allows staff users to view objects in a draft state. But I'm finding it difficult to write a unittest for this view.

I'm using Factory Boy for my setup:

```
class UserFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = User

    username = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda t: random_string())
    password = factory.PostGenerationMethodCall('set_password', 'mysecret')
    email = fuzzy.FuzzyText(
        length=12, suffix='@email.com').fuzz().lower()
    is_staff = True
    is_active = True

class ReleaseFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Release

    headline = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda t: random_string())
    slug = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda t: slugify(t.headline))
    author = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda t: random_string())
    excerpt = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda t: random_string())
    body = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda t: random_string())

class TestReleaseViews(TestCase):
    """
    Ensure our view returns a list of :model:`news.Release` objects.
    """

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()
        self.user = UserFactory.create()
        self.client.login(username=self.user.username, password=self.user.password)
```

Given that I now have a logged-in, staff user for my tests, how do I go about using that to test against for a view (status_code 200 instead of 404)?

For instance, this test fails (404 != 200) when my view allows for users with `is_staff` as True to access the view:

```
def test_staff_can_view_draft_releases(self):
    "ReleaseDetail view should return correct status code"
    release = ReleaseFactory.create(status='draft')
    response = self.client.get(
        reverse(
            'news:release_detail',
            kwargs={
                'year': release.created.strftime('%Y'),
                'month': release.created.strftime('%b').lower(),
                'day': release.created.strftime('%d'),
                'slug': release.slug
            }
        )
    )
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually, you receive a `404` error because the `self.client.login` call fails.

When you're passing `password=self.user.password`, you're sending the hash of the password, not the password itself.

When you call `UserFactory()`, the steps taken by factory_boy in your factory are:

1. Create an object with `{'username': "<random>", 'is_active': True, 'is_staff': True, 'email': "<fuzzed>@email.com"}`
2. `save()` it
3. Call `user.set_password('my_secret')`
4. Call `user.save()` again

By then, `user.password` is the *result* of `set_password('my_secret')`, not `'my_secret'`.

I'd go for (in your test):

```
pwd = 'my_super_secret'
self.user = UserFactory(password=pwd)
self.client = Client()
self.assertTrue(self.client.login(username=self.user.username, password=pwd))
```

By the way, the declaration of your email field won't work as you expect it: when you write `fuzzy.FuzzyText(...).fuzz().lower()`, this gets executed **only once**, when the `UserFactory` class is declared.

You should instead use `factory.fuzzy.FuzzyText(chars='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', length=12, suffix='@example.com')`.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way than using the client, I have found it is helpful to instantiate the view and directly pass it the request.

```
self.request.user = UserFactory()
view = ReleaseView.as_view()
response = view(self.request)
```

And then you can

```
self.assertEqual(response.status_code, desired_status_code)
```

And even render the response if you so desire.

Comment: Thanks! How would I use the client should I continue down this route?

Comment: I would do a little debugging - do you intend to return a `403` if a user is not staff rather than `404`? I would check in the view why it would be failing and log it to stdout. Otherwise it looks like you have it setup correctly for factory boy. Does PostGeneration set the value of password correctly? What happens if you directly pass in the password rather than `user.password`?